# Facing issue on password() function after upgrading to Mysql 8 for 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench, database-administration, mysql-8.0

I have upgraded my MYSQL to 8.0.33 version from 5.7,When I run the below query I AM getting error as password() function is not supported/deprecated from 8.x versions

This is my 5.7 mysql query:-

```
    SET PASSWORD FOR 'dbusertest'@'%' = PASSWORD('randomPassword')
```

can someone help me with the equivalent query, I was trying this but getting error

```
     SET PASSWORD FOR 'dbusertest'@'%' = CONCAT('*', 
    UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('randomPassword')))))
```

Comment: Use MD5(), SHA() or SHA2() instead. Or use `TO RANDOM`.

Comment: Can you help me with equivalent query I was trying this but didnt work SET PASSWORD FOR 'dbusertest'@'%' = CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('${randomPassword}')))))

Comment: You cannot do this - on version 8+ the authentication string is literal value, not an expression. And I cannot understand why do you need in such complex expression.

Comment: Can you help me how to achieve it via SHA2() I am still getting error if i am doing SET PASSWORD FOR 'user'@'%' =  SHA2('mypass');

Comment: Is I have said **the authentication string is literal value, not an expression**. Your `SHA2('mypass')` is NOT string literal. Provide the password literal and set needed authentication plugin for the user. Alternatively you may compose needed SQL statement text and execute it dynamically, as prepared statement (SET and ALTER USER are permitted in dynamic SQL).

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me and it works fine in both the versions of MYSQL

```
       ALTER USER 'dbusertest' IDENTIFIED BY 'randomPassword';
```